# Empty file when reading contents - Google Drive API Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, google-drive-android-api

I´ve read a lot about the Google Drive API for Android in the last 5 days and I didn't find a single piece of information that I could use for my project. So I´ve decided to come here, hoping that some of you brillant guys could help me out.

I am using Android Studio 2.1.3 and play-services:9.4.0 and I'm able to upload a .txt file to my root folder on Google Drive without problems. However, when I try to get the file content to copy to another .txt, the final file turns out empty. So tried to verify, after the query, the file's size on the metadata buffer and it's empty too. I don´t know what else to do. Follow my code:

GoogleApiClient:

```
api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    api.connect();
```

Function to create files:

```
 public void createFiles() {
    sendFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sendTest");
    receiveFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "receiveTest");

    if (!sendFolder.exists())
        sendFolder.mkdirs();
    if (!receiveFolder.exists())
        receiveFolder.mkdirs();

    testSend = new File(sendFolder, "test.txt");

    FileOutputStream f = null;
    try {
        f = new FileOutputStream(testSend);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.println("Test Test Test Test Test");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Upload the file:

```
public void sendFile() {
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(api).setResultCallback(backupContentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> backupContentsCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("test.txt") // Google Drive File name
                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                .setStarred(true).build();
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(api)
                .createFile(api, changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                .setResultCallback(backupFileCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> backupFileCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }
        mfile = result.getDriveFile();
        mfile.open(api, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, new DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long bytesExpected) {
            }
        }).setResultCallback(backupContentsOpenedCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> backupContentsOpenedCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }

        DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(contents.getOutputStream());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        try {
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(testSend.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            while( ( n = bis.read(buffer) ) > 0 ) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
            bos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        contents.commit(api, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Uploaded successfully.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Copy file content:

```
private void receiveFileSync() {
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "test.txt"))
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(api, query).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
            long size = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().get(0).getFileSize();

            showMessage(" Size: " + size);

            driveId = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().get(0).getDriveId();
            metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().release();
            mfile = driveId.asDriveFile();
            mfile.open(api, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, new DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytesDown, long bytesExpected) {
                }
            }).setResultCallback(restoreContentsCallback);
        }
    });
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> restoreContentsCallback =
    new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }
            testReceive = new File(receiveFolder, "test.txt");

            DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
            try {
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(contents.getInputStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testReceive.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int n;

                while( ( n = in.read(buffer) ) > 0) {
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
                bos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            contents.discard(api);
        }
    };
```

The size that I get on `showMessage(" Size: " + size);` is 0. I think that means I can´t read. Do you guys know how to fix this without migrating to Google REST?

Thanks in advance!